# How i can assign this array into another array in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

Hi i come cross problem where i want to assign an array in to another array

like i have this value save in DB of a attribute of table like

```
      ["rogid", "soni"]

      a_array = []
```

after retrieving from DB i want to assign as it

```
      a_array =  ["rogid", "soni"]
```

after assign  it should look like this after i display

```
      ["rogid", "soni"]
```

but when i display a_array it is like this

```
     ["[\"rogid\", \"soni\"]"]
```

how i can achive it like same as ["rogid", "soni"]

Many many thanks for help

Comment: Please show us the code as you have it now so that we know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: Looks like you convert your array to string and back to array somehow. ["rogid", "soni"].to_s.to_a => ["[\"rogid\", \"soni\"]"]

Comment: @RyanBigg when i use this <%=answer.other_software  %> it write on view ["rogid", "soni"] just like string array

Comment: @RyanBigg how i assign this string array after retrieving from DB same as to another array

Comment: @RyanBigg actually <%=answer.other_software %> this code give me a string like ["rogid", "soni"] and how i can make it a string array.   Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regex to parse the string:
[rogid an soni on rubular](http://rubular.com/r/yAaaFpn77e)

Im getting some odd ruby behavior here so i cannot confirm this answer right now, but im pretty sure you can handle it:

[REGEX](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html)

`my_pattern.match(my_string).to_a` will return you desired array.
Also dont forget pull `"[\"rogid\", \"soni\"]"` from `["[\"rogid\", \"soni\"]"]` before using the regex.